Are there approaches to deriving a Grammar(production rules) from given set of strings?
Apologies for unambiguous question. So far I have a lot of difficulties of discerning on how to design formal production rules for some formal language aside from classic examples such as equal pairs of a's and b's or palindromes.
This is more of a generalistic question but I have noticed a lot of my answers to problem sets have 'dead' productions or sometimes unnecessary ones.
For instance I know that 1* can easily be represented as $$A \mapsto 1A \mid \epsilon $$
But also
$$ A \mapsto A1 | \epsilon $$
Which causes confusion in grander context.
Last question I pondered to no avail is
$$L(G) =\{w|a^i b^j c^{i+j}~  such ~that~i>j>0\} $$
And I can't seem to make a decent start, the only "clue" that I am sure is correct is that $$j \geq 1 \land i \geq 2$$
Answers are much appreciated.
